# CSS - How do I get my list element to fill 100% of the block

Tags: html, css

I want to use different sizes of list blocks.

In the 'Result' section of JSFiddle, the user can only select the "Working" list entry if he hovers near the top of the block (where the text is located).  If the user hovers below the text, it does not work.  I want the user to be able to hover over any portion of this block.

I have placed my code here

[JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/susan/5kDHS/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/susan/5kDHS/3/)

Any help that you can provide is appreciated.
Thanks, Susan.

```
<div id="mainblock"><b>My Day</b>
    <ul id="blocks">
        <li id="timework"><a href="http://www.google.com">Working 75% </a>
        </li>
        <li id="timeplay"><a href="http://espn.go.com/">Playing 25%</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
#blocks li a
{
    .......
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5kDHS/8/

I have made height of anchor tag equals to 100% of it's parents li

Comment: That's great.
Thanks so much.  (I'm so new to this.)

Comment: Note the anchors exceed their containers now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain the padding for the anchors, you could try using a CSS calculation.

```
#blocks li a
{
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    color: #333333;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    height: calc(100% - 20px); /* <----- added this */
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

This allows the anchors to fill the containers but also subtracts the amount of padding. If you simply use `height: 100%;' you'll find the anchors exceed their containers due to padding.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/5kDHS/10/) (Only tested in Chrome)

Other than this it may require an additional span inside the anchors items to create the desired padding.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I'll play with those settings.  Thanks Scott.  much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `height: 100%;` to `#blocks li a`. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5kDHS/6/